# How to show some elements in View based on current user login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 types of roles for users eg: User & admin.
I want to show `Update` link when login role is user , but when role is Admin n `update` and `delete` both link should appear in `view` Module.

how can I achieve this ? here is my code of view. in which I want to put both link for `update` and `delete` based on user role.

```
@model List<WebApplication5.Models.MyModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Show</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:aliceblue">

    <div>
       @TempData["Message"]

        <b><center>Data Of Table</center></b>
        <table style="background-color:azure" border="1" align="center" title="DATA OF EMPLOYEE">

                @foreach (var objmymodel in Model)
                { 
                    <tr>
                       <td>@objmymodel.Username</td>
                       <td>@objmymodel.Password</td>  

                       <td>@Html.ActionLink("delete", "Delete", new {id=@objmymodel.Id })</td>
                       <td>@Html.ActionLink("update", "Update", new { id = @objmymodel.Id })</td>


                    </tr>
                }
        </table>
    </div>


    <div>@Html.ActionLink("Logout","Login","Mycontroller")</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is code of ADO class if i enter admin as user name and password than redirect to show data  page as admin or check in data base for username

```
        public static void Logindata(MyModel objmymodel)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\nisarg parekh\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
            con.Open();

            if(objmymodel.Username=="admin" && objmymodel.Password=="admin")
            {

                usernamestring = "admin";
                message = "welcome    " + objmymodel.Username;

            }
            else
            {
            string check = "select Username,Password from tb1 where Username='"+objmymodel.Username+"' and Password='"+objmymodel.Password+"'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(check,con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();



            if (dr.Read())
            {

                usernamestring = objmymodel.Username;
                message ="welcome    "+ objmymodel.Username;
            }
            else
            {
                message = "FAIL";
            }
            }
```

here is code of Controller

```
 public ActionResult Login()
        {


            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(MyModel objmymodel)
        {


            ado.Logindata(objmymodel);

            TempData["Message"] = ado.message;

            if (ado.message == "FAIL")
            {
                objmymodel.Username = "";
                objmymodel.Password = "";
                return RedirectToAction("Login");

            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = ado.usernamestring;

                return RedirectToAction("Show");
            }

        }
```

Comment: How do you know if an admin is logged in or normal user?

Comment: Can you share for code of controller which populates the model and returns the view?

Comment: @lazzy i put my code of ado class and controller in my question please check it.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya i put code of controller and ado class in my question. please check it.

Comment: `public ActionResult Login()` does not pass any model to the view. On what base you are expecting the values in UI? Did you debug the code ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya obvio first method is [httpget] so it return blank view for login, and when i click on button then it is calling [httppost] public ActionResult Login() function .

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya code is working properly.

Comment: please visit this ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138070/asp-net-mvc-authentication-hide-element-in-view-based-on-roles] link

Comment: @Lucifer Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to follow below task.

**-First Approach**

1. Create Role for your Application.
   [Creating Roles in Asp.net Identity MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697226/creating-roles-in-asp-net-identity-mvc-5?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
2. On Registration assign Role to your user. [How to assign a Role to a user in MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217528/how-to-assign-a-role-to-a-user-in-mvc5?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
3. Now based on role you can disable/enable Links. [Hide link based on Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078423/hide-link-based-on-role?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

**-Second Approach**

Create two views of current show view (all the remaining data except these links remains same)

```
 a. With Update and Delete Link
 b. only With Update Link
```

In controller, put check on user name, if user is admin then render first view(a) else render second view (b).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property (HasAdminAccess) in Model,  and use this to check on view and render buttons accordingly.

**Model:**

```
public class MyModel
{
   // Your other props.

   public bool HasAdminAccess { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller/ Action:**

```
if (objmymodel.Username == "admin" && objmymodel.Password == "admin") {

         usernamestring = "admin";
         message = "welcome    " + objmymodel.Username;
         objmymodel.HasAdminAccess = true;
 }
```

**View:**

```
@if (Model.HasAdminAccess)
{
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("delete", "Delete", new {id = @objmymodel.Id})</td>
}
<td>@Html.ActionLink("update", "Update", new { id = @objmymodel.Id })</td>
```

*

> When you first request(GET) HasAdminAccess, will have false and delete
>   button would not be rendered.

- 

Comment: HasaAdminAcccess is a column of Database? @vikas Chaturvedi

Comment: It's up to you how you want to build your application and manage your roles.